# Intellij IDEA how to modify the font color in `quick documentation`

Tags: intellij-idea, colors

Just as the following pic, the red color is a little harsh.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't think there is any way to customize the presentation of Quick Documentation; you are stuck with whatever the theme provides.

While you can customize the Javadoc colors used in your source (**File > Settings... > Editor > Color Scheme > Java > Comments > JavaDoc**), that has no effect on the Quick Documentation.

Issue [WEB-28147 JSDoc. Documentation features](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-28147) has been raised to address this for JavaScript, specifically requesting *Add custom colors and format for the quick doc window*. You could [raise a similar issue for Java](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/reporting-issues.html#d436202e62).

As a related matter, issue [IDEA-161974 Enabling font choice for code in quick documentation.](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-161974) has been raised to support modifying the font used for Quick Documentation.